# NodeJS http get timeout

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have the following code which is creating issues:

```
var timeout_wrapper = function (req) {
    return function () {
        log.error('rest', 'Unable to contact service. Timed out.');
        if (res.req) {
            res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send('Timed out contacting service.');
        }

        req.abort();
    };
};

var timeout;

var req = https.get(options, function (response) {
    log.info('rest', 'Got response from service.');
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    if (response.statusCode === HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
        callback(false);
        return;
    }
    if (response.statusCode === HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) {
        callback(true);
        return;
    }

    log.error('rest', 'Service returned an undocumented status code: %s', response.statusCode);
    res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send('Unable to contact service.');
}).on('error', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    log.error('rest', 'Unable to contact service. Got error: %s', e);
    /*if (res.req) {
        res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send('Unable to contact service.');
    }*/
});

timeout = setTimeout(timeout_wrapper(req), 10000);
```

The service I am contacting is timing out quite often (but I have no control over that). So I created a timeout function, which works (the client is indeed receiving `res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send('Timed out contacting service.');` ), but the request is not aborted. The `.on('error', ...)` is called a while after with the following stacktrace:

```
ERR! rest  Error: socket hang up
ERR! rest     at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
ERR! rest     at CleartextStream.socketCloseListener (http.js:1522:23)
ERR! rest     at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
ERR! rest     at tls.js:696:10
ERR! rest     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
ERR! rest  Unable to contact service. Got error: %s { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

I thought this was a simple HTTPS GET request, not a socket, and why is the request not aborted in my timeout function?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need crate a timeout_wrapper for this situation. A simple solution would be put `http.get` inside a function with a callback as parameter. This one may not be flexible as your solution, but looks simpler and should work in this situation.

```
function testGet(options, callback) {
    var req = http.get(options, function(response) {

        if (response.statusCode === HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
           callback(false);

        if (response.statusCode === HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
           callback(true);

        if (response.statusCode == ERROR)
           callback(false);

    }).on('error', function(e){
        callback(false);
    });

    req.setTimeout(TIMEOUT, function(){
        callback(false);
        req.abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Comment: Oh, sorry. thiis is my first answer.

Comment: It is not to late to improve the answer.  Below your post on the left is an edit button.  If you can explain the post better, feel to edit it so that it is a better answer for others who may come later.

Comment: Nice work!  This is a much better answer now.  Do not hesitate to make edits to improve the site.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to answer my question above, however I resolved my issue by using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package which is, in my opinion, much better than Node's own HTTP package. It supports timeout out of the box, among other things.